# How to Conditional Format based off a Google Sheets Query function?

Tags: google-sheets, import, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting, google-query-language

I have a google sheet that is doing to two queries and would like to highlight all cells if data was pulled in off a certain sheet.

```
 {QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url1", "Sheet1!$A:$Z"), 
   "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col15,Col17,Col18,Col7,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14 WHERE Col15 IS NOT NULL, 1);
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url2", "Sheet2!$A3:$Z"),
   "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15 WHERE Col17 = '1',1)}
```

I would like to have "Sheet2" to be highlighted all the way through while keeping Sheet1 generic. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be if you add helper column (which you can hide) based of you can setup conditional formatting. fx would go like this:

```
={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url1", "Sheet1!$A:$Z"), 
"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col15,Col17,Col18,Col7,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,'Sheet1' 
 WHERE Col15 IS NOT NULL, 1);
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url2", "Sheet2!$A3:$Z"),
 "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15,'Sheet2' 
 WHERE Col17 = '1',1)}
```

and then a simple cf:

```
=$N1="Sheet1"
```

Answer (score 0):

or you could paint it directly with custom fx:

```
=ROW(A1)<=ROWS(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url1", "Sheet1!$A:$Z"), 
 "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col15 IS NOT NULL, 1))
```

ofc all spreadsheets (importranges) needs to be connected by authorizing the access for each and every importrange